# ERROR: Error installing rails: ERROR: Failed to build gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, amazon-web-services, installation

I'm setting up servers. I'm installing rails on an Amazon Linux

Installed List: ruby, development tools, gems, zlib-devel, readline-devel.

I'm trying to install rails and now I'm stuck here

> $ sudo gem install rails Building native extensions.  This could take
> a while... ERROR:  Error installing rails:    ERROR: Failed to build gem
> native extension.
>
> ```
>     /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
> ```
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.3 for inspection. Results
> logged to
> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out

Is there a problem with this json library?

Answer (score 14):

You need to install the following

```
yum install ruby-devel
yum install make
yum install gcc
```

Comment: After browsing a million forums, this did this trick. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be using Ruby 1.9.x, to upgrade Ruby:

```
sudo yum install ruby19
```

and also

```
sudo yum install ruby19-devel
sudo yum install make
sudo yum install gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed rvm, make sure to use `rvm gem install rails`

Answer (score -3):

THe problem has nothing to do with RVM. The problem is you need ruby source header files. Compile ruby from source(RVM does that) or install the appropiate headers for your ruby version.
What is amazon linux(there is not such thing) ? is it ubuntu or what ?
How did you installed ruby ? what does ruby -v says ?

Comment: If you are unable to understand a question, research it before questioning the person who asked it. Look up Amazon EC2 and the Amazon Linux AMI file.